# How to tell an UIView about an event in a collectionviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller, uiview

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3joYC.png)

Hello!

I'm making a Swift project using the MVC pattern, and I'm hoping you guys could help me with how to best pass information between different classes.

I'll do my best to describe, but please take a look at my badly drawn reference for some additional clarity.

The project is build with a Model, that's a simple class with the rules of the project, a View Controller, that has an instance of both the View and the Model, passes information between them and initiates the View.

The View has all the element variables, and sets the layout. The view has a CollectionViewController, that in turn has the CollectionViewCells. One of those cell has a Button. There's of course some other classes, but they're not relevant.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I want the user to click the Button in the CollectionViewCell. The CollectionViewCell should then tell the View that the Button was pressed, and the View should take some Information and send to the ViewController, that will interpret it for the Model.

More or less Button > User Clicks -> (CollectionViewController) -> View > View collects Information -> CollectionView -> Model.

I cannot delegate the buttonclick event to the View, as UIViews cannot be delegated to. I can use a Closure to send the buttonclick event to the CollectionViewController, but I don't seem to be able to send it further from there.

So the two alternatives I'm looking at is creating a NotificationCenter just to tell the View a button has been pressed, or making the View a ViewController too. Neither seems ideal. Does anyone have a better solution, or any insight on what I should do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution based on your reference image can be this:
you can send your click event with clouser to your collectionView parent view and in your view have a weak instance of your parent viewController. when the clouser called, you can call the method from your parent instance and update your model